# window form calling a web service and displaying results

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, visual-studio-2008, iis

i want to create a form, where i can press a button and it will call a web service, and then display the array list result

does anyone know where i can find some examples? or maybe someone wants to show me some code,i am new to this and would love to learn

even if you can give me an example of calling a web service and getting 3 fields returned and based on a 1 or 0 it will check a check box (a check box for each field), ill be able to edit it and add all 40 fields etc

this is a web service that i need to send in a user name and password (which the application already knows what it is) and then i need to specify a 1 thru 8 (depends which role i want returned)
or 0 to get all roles back

the web service returns multiple fields, with a 1 or 0, its called user roles,.
so lets say role 1 shows whats allowed, role 2 has the same fields but where role #1 may have a 1 or 0, on role#2 its not always the same 1 or 0
here is an example of results when asking for Role ID 1

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
    <GetRoleResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <GetRoleResult>
    <ID>int</ID>
    <RoleName>string</RoleName>
    <Weather>int</Weather>
    <National>int</National>
    <International>int</International>
    <Local>int</Local>
    <TabEmail>int</TabEmail>
    </GetRoleResult>
    </GetRoleResponse>
    </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to consume a web service is to use visual studio to create a web service reference, all you need is the URL for the web-service you are using.
[example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Then you need to use the web service you simple create and instance and call the method you want. [example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6h0yh8f9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: i have the reference build,.  i dont know how to create the form (where to start) and to tell it by pressing a button to call the web service and then display the results in a datagridview, or even in a list result and i can click on one and have a new window with all fields checked or unchecked based if its a 1 or 0 receive for that field,. i have edited an existing form to add fields etc, but i dont know where to start from scratch, and i kind of want to start from scratch with some good guidance,.

Comment: This should show you how to create a winforms application.
http://cplus.about.com/od/learnc/ss/random_2.htm 
If you're using .NET 4 you may want to go with WPF instead but they are similar.
With the on button click event you can call you're web service, then set the data that is returned to be the datasource for the datagridview and then call the databind event.

Comment: i cant find clear instructions on how to start,. i need some examples of a web service being called, (which i do know how to set a button to call a web service),. but i need help on how to parse the results, i want to check a box or not check a box based on the results. please if anyone can help me.

Comment: Here is an example:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/cpwebserviceconsumer.aspx
There are plenty of other examples of consuming webs services available on the web. Microsoft has made consuming web services very simple, after you have a webservice reference and initialise it calls to the webservice are exactly the same as calling any other method.

Comment: i am so bad at this, that its still confusing and i cant figure it out,.